# How to Block Certain Kubernetes User to Issuing Certain Commands

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

For example, I don't want this user to :

- Edit Cluster
- Edit Deployment
- Edit ig
- Delete Pods
  ...

But Allow this user to:

- Get nodes
- Get pods
- Describe Pods

If I use RBAC, can I have guidance?

Comment: does danny kaplunski's answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

you will need to use RBAC for that, after creating a user you will need to create (ROLE or CLUSTER ROLE depends if you want it to apply to a specific namespace or not) and then create (ROLE BINDING or CLUSTER ROLE BINDING) and bind between the user and the role you created.
you can find it all here https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/